# Calculating train animation speed based on distance

Tags: unity, mathematics, animation

I have an **animation clip** of a train which is covering about a 16707-meter distance in 56.66667 seconds. So that's:

- distance covered (from start to end position by animation ) = 16707
- Animation length (in seconds) = 56.66667

Now I want it to complete the animation in 9 minutes. How should I calculate the ideal speed so that the train reaches its destination in 9 minutes from the starting point of the animation?

Comment: That's a really long animation. Is the animation unique for the full duration or just a repeat?

Comment: The train is moving over a path!

Comment: But why would the single animation need to be almost 1min? For a train, that would be for me the movement of the wheels, maybe some light and or steam/ smoke. Repeating itself for the desired route. And those animations are usually a few seconds long.

Comment: Maybe it's a monorail that doesn't have any of those extra articulations to animate, or they're animated by script or a layered clip. While this sounds like a better application for splines than one long animation clip, I think the question is still answerable in its current form - even if you wouldn't implement the feature this way. 

Comment: That is true, I'm trying to prevent unnecessary extra complications, the lengths just seemed odd. Stretching the animation to 9 minutes seems to be basic math in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a playback speed as:

```
float desiredLengthInSeconds = 9f * 60f; // 9 Minutes * 60 seconds per minute

float playbackSpeedRatio = animationClip.length / desiredLengthInSeconds;
```

Then if you're using an `Animation` component, apply that speed as:

```
foreach (var state in animationComponent) {
    state.speed = playbackSpeedRatio;
}
```

Or for an `Animator` component:

```
animatorComponent.speed = playbackSpeedRatio;
```

Since the total distance travelled is 16707 m, covered in 540 s (9 minutes), that means the train is travelling at an average speed of 16707/540 = 31.93888... m/s.